# Implementing a Measurement type parameter on an iOS App Intent

Tags: sirikit, appintents

Apple state that the `Measurement` type can be used wrapped with `@Property` on an App Intent and used with Siri...

I've tried to implement this and get a warning that `UnitLength` isn't Sendable and secondly Siri doesn't seem to understand any kind of response to the request for this measurement.

```
struct LogMileageIntent: AppIntent, CustomIntentMigratedAppIntent, PredictableIntent {
    
    ...

    @Parameter(title: "Measurement")
    var measurement: Measurement<UnitLength>

    ...
}
```

Has anyone got this working?